# Select identicle columns from two tables while insertion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two identical tables on different databases

```
Database : live
table : customer
id | name | email | address
```

and

```
Database : test
table : customer
id | name | email | address | phone | post_code | company
```

This is only sample structure. I have 15 fields in live database table and 35 fields in test database table. I want to write a query which can insert data from live to test database table. How can i do that. I have tried this

```
INSERT INTO test.customer
SELECT *
FROM live.customer as cd
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from test.customer);
```

This inserts the data in the wrong columns if they are not in the same order.
And this is the other way i have tried

```
INSERT INTO test.customer (id,name,email,address)
SELECT *
FROM live.customer as cd
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from test.customer);
```

This is fine but i dont want to write 15 column names. How can i select all columns from live database table and put its result into () in insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a pure SQL solution to this. But you could use a dynamic query, created this way:

```
SET @sql = null;

SELECT
  CONCAT('INSERT INTO test.customer (',
    group_concat(CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '`') separator ','),
    ') SELECT ',
    group_concat(CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '`') separator ','),
    ' FROM live.customer WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * from test.customer)')
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='customer' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test'
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT * FROM test_customer;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c6b2/5).

Comment: @raheelshan I updated my answer a little, since there's no guarantee that using GROUP_CONCAT column names are always returned in the same order, it's better to specify column names also on the SELECT part instead of using *, and I also added a CONCAT to quote column names, hope this helps :)